# Making one function to UPDATE and INSERT using REPLACE INTO in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to make one php function to UPDATE or INSERT a row into a MySQL database table.

tubeTable SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tubeTable` (
  `tubeID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sampleName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `sampleType` enum('Antibody','Bacterial_Cultures','Blood','Body_fluids','Bone','Cell_Lines','Chemical','Chemical','Cytokine','DNA','Plasma','RNA','Serum','Urine','Virus','Whole_Tissue') DEFAULT NULL,
  `freezeDate` date NOT NULL,
  `creationTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `experimentName` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `labBook` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pageNum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `published` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mta` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `public` enum('y','n') NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tubeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tubeID` (`tubeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userID` (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=430 ;
```

The php function makes this REPLACE INTO SQL

```
REPLACE INTO    tubeTable 
SET 
            tubeID = "", 
            sampleName = "Tube 6",
            freezeDate = "2016-09-06",
            color = "white",
            labBook = "lab book",
            pageNum = "3",
            sampleType = "Virus",
            experimentName = "experiment name",
            userID = "2",
            published = "", 
            mta = "";
```

However, this only deletes the last row in the table and then inserts the new data as a new record.

Therefore if I run the above REPLACE INTO statement 5 times I only get one record.  When I expect 5 records with increasing tubeID's.

Currently this table only has one record in it.  The data looks like:

```
tubeID = "429", 
sampleName = "Tube 7",
freezeDate = "2016-09-06",
color = "white",
labBook = "lab book",
pageNum = "3",
sampleType = "Virus",
experimentName = "experiment name",
userID = "2",
published = "0", 
mta = "0",
public = "public"
creationTime = '2016-09-06 18:40:41';
```

Comment: why use `replace`, then? That's not for creating a NEW records. it'll delete old ones and replace them with a single record. you want a regular plain `insert` query.

Comment: I would like to have one function which inserts and updates.  I know I could use INSERT but REPLACE is suppose to do both:"REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted."

Comment: The key phrase here is "**a** UNIQUE index", as in not all; it is functioning exactly as expected because it is seeing there is already a row with userId = 2.  ....also, why say "last row", when you later reveal it is the ONLY row?

Comment: if you want to update existing records, then do `insert ... on duplicate key update`. replace also has the side effect of triggering `on delete` cascades if you have any foreign keys, because it first deletes the original record, and inserts a new one. you may NOT want that to happen.